# psql saying database does not exist but it does exist in pgadmin

Tags: postgresql

I have just installed Postgres v10.4 on Windows and created, using pgadmin, a new database called analysis. It is there, I can see it in pgadmin, and it has one table in it. However, I cannot connect to this database using psql.

[image]

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -d postgres -U postgres
psql (10.4)
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# l
postgres-# \l
                                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |           Collate           |            Ctype            |   Access privileges
-----------+----------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 |
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                             |                             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |                             |                             | postgres=CTc/postgres
(3 rows)


postgres-# \q

C:\WINDOWS\system32>psql -d analysis -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  database "analysis" does not exist

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

I don't know what I'm doing with psql, but all I've found is that I can connect to db postgres as user postgres. There's a `\l` command and it shows 3 databases (2 of which, template0 and template1) I can't even see in pgadmin.

How can I connect to the database (analysis) that I've just created in pgadmin? Can anybody explain what user I'm logged in under in pgadmin, if it's different to 'postgres' and if it isn't, how is it that I can't see in psql what I can see in pgadmin?

Comment: As someone else said, you may be connecting to different local clusters. This happened to me when I had two different versions of postgres installed. Try running `pg_lsclusters` in your command prompt and post the output.

Comment: Do you mean running pg_lsclusters at the windows cmd line?  It doesn't recognise the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template0 and template1 are know as skeleton databases. When you use CREATE DATABASE command postgres copy the existing databae.
By default template1 database is used to create new database.

I think your pgadmin and psql are connected to different cluster. A cluster in postgresql is collection of one or more databases in a single instance of server

The image you posted does not show the complete view of pgadmin browser. But
if there are 2 cluster then you can see in pgadmin like "Servers(2)". To find running port of each cluster right click on corresponding cluster and select properties then click connection tab. Here port number can be seen.
Then connect to cluster in psql using that Port.

Comment: Thank you. I had previously installed postgres from the non-enterprisedb location. I haven't uninstalled it only because it seems to have melded with the enterprisedb one.